# How do I change the guest session defaults

Tags: users, guest-session

I have a quite tunned up gnome desktop and I would like for the guest session to share most of the user settings, this includes:

- Gtk and Metacity themes.
- Number of panels, placement and applets.
- Applications that run on login.

I'm having a hard time finding where this configuration files are placed in the filesystem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has become much easier in 11.10.

First you need to create a folder: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/guest-session/skel/`. The -p switch creates /etc/guest-session so you can place /skel in it in one go. Now you just add the files you want to /etc/guest-session/skel and it will be copied onto the guest account whenever it's created.

The program that sets this up is /usr/sbin/guest-account in case you want to learn more about what's going on.

The tutorial [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) elaborates on this topic. In particular it describes how you can create a "special purpose user" for a convenient way to customize the guest session appearance and behavior, without having to know which files to edit.

Answer (score 5):

The guest session is recreated every time as a "default new user" with the `/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/guest-session-setup.sh` script, which is part of the `gdm-guest-session` package.  I don't see any *clean* way to make it include your settings into the guest session.

You could of course change the way every new user's $HOME gets created, but I'm not sure that's really what you want (I won't consider it a *"clean"* solution to do it that way).

Comment: I will take a look at the script. It must take the preferences from somewhere. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: No, it doesn't have to take the preferences from anywhere, as applications use the system-wide defaults when no user-preferences are set.

Comment: > /usr/share/gdm/guest-session/guest-session-setup.sh

This script appears to no longer exist in Ubuntu 11.10. Does anyone know how to find it?

I was using it to change the guest session default keyboard layout.

Comment: See my answer for the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure.. but I've always followed the steps [on this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1294501) under sections `login as guest` where you can customize the account. Then section `freeze it` where you actually setup `rsync` to reset the account on PC startup. You can easily modify this to reset on logout or shutdown. Been working great for me.