# How to change the default wallpaper of a guest account

Tags: default, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the guest session defaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults)

I want to change the default wallpaper of my guest account, so I can instantly identify if my computer is logged into the guest account. How would I go about doing this