# Customize guest Account?

Tags: 11.10, users, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the guest session defaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults)

I am using 11.10 with single user, sometime when someone wants my system i can't deny so i have to give them my pc along user account password .

I was willing if i give them my guest account but when i open guest account and discover that there is something i wish to change . i want 2 hide some of application from guest user . if needed i set password for *guest user* . i want some customization on privileged of guest account ?

is that Possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data for guest accounts are stored in the temporary folder, so they are lost on reboot.

If you are happy to have a password for the account, may I suggest you create a brand new account? Customise that account as you need.

To hide an application is a bit more tricky. Obviously, you can remove it from the guest account's menu, but a determined person could find it anyway. You can use [sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) to prevent that account from running the application, but -- again -- a determined person may well find it anyway.