# How to make Guest save theme changes on log-out/shut-down/restart?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, logout, sleep, guest-session

Ubuntu 12.04

At the moment I'm trying to recover my password on my only account, (but it auto-logs in) so I use the Guest when the computer logs-out/sleeps on my administrator account. So I change the background etc., when I use the guest session again all my changes are deleted.

So how do I make these changes permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. I'm sure there's a way, if you find the script that cleans everything up. But the guest account is supposed to be cleaned after every logout. It's the very definition of the Guest account.

You can change the settings that it starts with. Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults) for information on how to do that.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me to get and delete the script?

Comment: On my system it's `/usr/sbin/guest-account` however this will almost certainly break something. It would take far less time to just reset the user password.

Comment: Reboot, and when you auto login open terminal. Type `passwd`. That will reset your password.