# How to Customize the Temporary Guest Account (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, guest-session

I configured Ubuntu to load the temporary guest account on start and would like to customize the desktop of the the temporary guest user account. How can I customize desktop of the temporary guest account?

I would like to accomplish the following tasks:

- Grant access to Firefox application only
- Restrict access to all other applications
- On start, load Firefox application
- On start, load specific webpage on Firefox
- Restrict Firefox to specific websites

Any help provided would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9515/how-do-i-change-the-guest-session-defaults

Comment: And for all of the firefox stuff, I would use a login script to open Firefox. You can set the startup pages in Firefox. In terms of restricting Firefox, check here: http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Websites-on-Firefox